# Multiple A/B Tests on same population

Tags: bonferroni, ab-test

I ran the same A/B test three times in a row for an email campaign. For each test I assigned a person to one of two groups (variation 1 or variation 2) randomly.

This way it could have happen that on different tests, the person has been assigned to different variations (e.g. variation 1, variation 2, again variation 1).

The test results look like this

First round:

```
| name        | receivers | persons clicked |
| variation 1 | 1000      | 10              |
| variation 2 | 1000      | 30              |
```

Second round:

```
| name        | receivers | persons clicked |
| variation 1 | 1000      | 50              |
| variation 2 | 1000      | 100             |
```

Third round:

```
| name        | receivers | persons clicked |
| variation 1 | 1000      | 30              |
| variation 2 | 1000      | 60              |
```

Every round separately is has a significant difference.

But what is the correct way to look at them as a whole? I know that the alpha error correction (Bonferroni correction) is a good way to go. But is this everything I have to consider? (Especially as one person could have been in both variations.)

Comment: Welcome to our site! There is no need to thank in advance here - it might seem impolite but we like to keep the questions focused on the matter at hand. Best way to thank someone who helped you is to upvote their answer (when you have enough reputation to) and accept (green tick) the one that helped you the most